# Java 1.7: synchronize(this) faster than synchronize void

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization

I'm currently implementing a multi-threaded version of Barnes-Hut algorithm for the N-body problem. While the algorithm works, it's not very optimized and I'm trying to reduce the run time of my program.

I've made sure that there are several threads that accurately find borders of the space I'm working with and realized that the code in the highest level object that I set the borders in is fairly unoptimized. It looks like this:

```
public synchronized void setBorders(float maxX, float minX, float maxY, float minY, int thread){
  if(maxX > this.maxX){ 
     this.maxX = maxX;  
  }
  if(maxY > this.maxY){ 
     this.maxY = maxY;  
  }
  if(this.minX > minX){ 
     this.minX = minX;  
  }
  if(this.minY > minY){ 
   this.minY = minY;    
  }
}
```

I have several threads attempting to access this method once they've figured out their respective values. Since a synchronized object can only be accessed by a single thread at a given time, this can be significantly improved.

On possible solution that I thought of was to remove the "public synchronized void" and rewrite the code into this:

```
public synchronized void setBorders(float maxX, float minX, float maxY, float minY, int thread){
  Synchronize(this){      
    if(maxX > this.maxX){ 
       this.maxX = maxX;    
    }
  }

  Synchronize(this){
    if(maxY > this.maxY){ 
       this.maxY = maxY;    
    }
  }

  Synchronize(this){
    if(this.minX > minX){ 
       this.minX = minX;    
    }
  }

  Synchronize(this){
    if(this.minY > minY){ 
     this.minY = minY;  
    }
  }
}
}
```

If my understanding of the Synchronized block is correct, that only a single thread can access the code inside a Synchronize(this) block at any given time, this should speed up my code.

Will this work, or is there a reason I should avoid this that I've missed?

Edit: Wow, I'm amazed at the speed and accuracy of the help you guys give. I'm really thankful for all this!

Comment: I see several options here. The compiler may convert the latter code to the former code, since there is no code between the synchronization blocks, or the performance will be worse due to more synchronization contention. I don't really see how that would improve performance. Unless your idea was to use 4 different locks, instead of using `this`. Why don't you test it out and post results.

Comment: Almost certainly slower although the JVM is free to combine the different synchronized blocks in which case it'd be the same speed. The same as for almost all performance questions... measure it.

Comment: the synchronized modifier on the method declaration in the second example looks like a mistake. and it's hard to see the point of having multiple threads all contending to set the values of a single object, are you ok with an outcome where minX is set by one thread and minY is set by another thread?

Comment: "Shouldn't acquiring and releasing four locks be faster than acquiring and releasing one?" Umm, no. It should take about four times as long.

Comment: I'm not sure if the java compiler will remove the block to optimize it, so on that I can only guess.

Nathan: I'm entirely okay with different threads setting different values. I'm trying to find the points that are farther away from the center than the rest.

David: If I've understood synchronized correctly, it will enable different threads to access different parts of the same function without disturbing eachother

Comment: The synchronization [can be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25729938/581205) or it's effect minimized, but do you really think, it's the most costly part? I doubt it, unless you're running on hundreds of cores.

Comment: Maaartinus: This is far from the most costly part, but it was the first step that I'm taking to optimize the code further :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code should execute *extremely quickly*, so I doubt if splitting it up into more synchronized blocks will lessen contention.  I'd go with the single, function level synchronized.

However, if the code were doing more, e.g.

```
...
if(maxX > this.maxX){ 
   this.maxX = maxX; 
   doSomeSlowerCalculation();
   updateSomeComplexSharedDataStructure();
}
...
```

Then splitting it up into individual synchronized blocks could help

Answer (score 1):

There are three options to avoid or reduce synchronization:

### Use atomics

Using a class from Guava you can do

```
private final AtomicDouble maxX = new AtomicDouble(Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

and simply

```
while (true) {
     double currentMaxX = this.maxX.get();
     if (currentMaxX >= maxX) break;
     boolean ok = compareAndSet(currentMaxX, maxX);
     if (ok) break;
}
```

If you really have to use float, write your own class, a few line [like these](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicDouble.java?r=f8144b4df7eec5f1c9e6942d8d5ef734a8767fd9#134) would do.

no synchronization, just a [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).

### Double Checked Locking

With

```
private volatile float maxX;
```

and Java 1.5 or higher, the following will do

```
if (maxX > this.maxX) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (maxX > this.maxX) {
            this.maxX = maxX;  
        }
    }
}
```

### Minimize sharing

Compute your local max/min and only after a few iterations update the shared state. This is the easiest, but may not apply to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize this more effectively, you could break your setBorders routine into 4 methods (1 for each param) and use 4 locking Objects to lock each setter method individually... But this would only be more effective if your setters were being called individually (not always as a block) and/or weren't always called in the same order, or if you could do a quick escape from the setter when you determine the value isn't actually changing

Comment: making each thread synchronize _more_ is not (generally) going to make things faster.

Comment: @jtahlborn I understand what you're getting at... its like unnecessary/useless code blocks, right? But in this case, even if every thread was working the same way, locking variables individually would allow up to 4 threads to be processing at a time, rather than just 1... In any case, it depends on how your code is run.

Comment: with synchronized block, only one thread is "working" at a time.  and the work is trivial (simple assignment).  so your threads are just going to be fighting with each other 4 times as often for locks.

Answer (score 0):

First, adding synchronized to a method definition like

```
synchronized void foo() {
    ...
}
```

is the same thing as

```
void foo() {
    synchronized(this) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you nest synchronized blocks like your second example:

```
synchronized void foo() {
    synchronized(this) {
        ...
    }
    synchronized(this) {
        ...
    }
}
```

then the inner blocks don't have any effect on synchronization, the thread calling the method still has to acquire the object's monitor on entering the method, and releases it upon exiting.

If you remove the synchronized from the method so all you have is:

```
void foo() {
    synchronized(this) {
        ...
    }
    synchronized(this) {
        ...
    }
}
```

then as threads execute this code they will have to acquire each block separately. So if multiple threads are setting different variables then you may end up with the object having some fields set by one thread and other fields set by another.

With smaller synchronized blocks, the threads may spend more time contending for locks. For each of these blocks the scheduler has to decide which thread gets the lock next. Lock acquisition is not fair, there's no certainty about which thread will get the lock next.

It's not obvious the lower-granularity approach will be faster, it may be better to let a thread get in, set all the fields, and get out. The second example may just make the scheduler work harder for no good reason. The only certain difference is that the second approach will allow intermixing data from different threads.